# I have two copies of PHP installed on my Centos 7 server how do I tell which is being used by apache

Tags: php, apache, centos7

I have two copies of PHP in

```
/bin
/usr/bin
```

How can I tell which apache/httpd is using?

Comment: none of those 2, you're looking at php cli which is not what is run by apache, apache loads a shared library which will have a name of libphp5.so or similar. Follow the answer from Damien if you're looking to change some settings in php.ini. Or let us kmnow why you need to know locvation and what system you're on.

Comment: you probably have a `php.conf` file for adding php to apache. that'll tell you where/which .so is being loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to put a file in your documentroot with the following content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

And then open the file in a browser. The output will give you many details about your PHP installation (modules etc) and will also give you the used PHP version.

Some more information about the phpinfo() function can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at it now, it seems to show where php.ini is located but that is in `/etc` so no help. Which line am I looking for?

Comment: Keep in mind that the location of your php files often is -not- the location of the code being used by apache. PHP can be compiled in apache or be provided as a module. In that case you wont find php in any of those locations.

Comment: The PHP executable in /bin or /usr/bin will only be used if you are using cgi/fastcgi, which most likely you are not.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which one to install newrelic on top of if that helps?

Comment: ( good chance btw that the /usr/bin or the /bin version of the php executable is actually a symlink of the other )

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you with newrelic, since I have little knowledge about the product. It does strike me as odd that you need to point the install to the php executable instead of to ie. the php.ini or apache config.

Comment: `_SERVER["_"] => /bin/php` and `_SERVER["PWD"] => /usr/bin` in the PHP variables too.

Comment: `\bin` is a symlink to `\usr\bin`.. oops. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

1. Default

At the terminal type this:

```
which php
```

And that should tell what is being used by default

**{or}**

2. Go to apache httpd.conf and search for PHP and see where is :

> LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache.dll"

Is located.

Comment: Thanks, how can I be sure this is the one that httpd is using?

Comment: That will tell you where in your `path` is the first occurance of the php executable. It does not say anything about it being used by apache or not.

Comment: if you have done the standard apache installation, it usually uses the the default. Unless you have done some settings changes.

Comment: I like the {or} much better, and a proper answer. +'ed.

Comment: That line doesn't exist in my httpd.conf.. the only 'php' reference is 'index.php'

Comment: Ah, found it in one of the module confs, this doesn't help me decide where to install new relic though

Comment: just for my knowledge does method 1 and 2 pointing to the same location? What do you mean by new relic?

Comment: isn't the installation supposed to be done in the www directory?

Comment: Option 2 gave me: `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so` so not much help. newrelic gives me the two options above when installing the php_agent